# How to use react-hooks with redux and immutable js?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks, immutable.js

I am using react, redux with immutable js. I am facing a problem when I use useEffect or similar hooks with non-primitive data that effect is running even though it hasn't changed as I am using hoc recommended by [redux docs](https://redux.js.org/recipes/using-immutablejs-with-redux/#use-a-higher-order-component-to-convert-your-smart-components-immutablejs-props-to-your-dumb-components-javascript-props).

Does anyone has a solution or best practice for using immutable js and redux with react hooks?

This is my parent component.

```
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { setValue, getValue, getData } from "./store";

import "./styles.css";
import Child from "./Child";

export default function App() {
  const data = useSelector(getData);
  const value = useSelector(getValue);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(setValue(value + 1))}>
        Change Value
      </button>
      <Child value={value} data={data} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is child component which is wrapped with toJS hoc

```
import { toJS } from "./hoc";

function Child(props) {
  useEffect(() => {
    // this runs even if only props.value has changed.
    console.log(props.data, "changed"); 
  }, [props.data]);
  return <div>{props.value}</div>;
}

export default toJS(Child);
```

Reproducible example:
[image: Edit react-hooks-with-immutable-redux-store]

Comment: The hook should only run if the dependencies changed. So I think the issue is that `[props.data]` is considered to be different on every render. Could you share `props.data` content?

Comment: That's issue. props.data is different on every render because i am using immutable js in redux and in hoc there is .toJS function which creates new copy of object on every render. I am not sure how to handle such scenario.

Comment: @Alvaro if you open codesandbox, in store.js there is initialState which has content of props.data.

Comment: I think the issue is not related to Immutable, but to passing an object to the dependencies, which is considered to be new on every render. This might help you to search for a solution in similar questions. In general it is better to avoid objects in the dependencies array. If you can't avoid it, the solutions I've seen include using lodash `isEqual` so you are actually passing a boolean or `JSON.stringify` the object so you are passing a string.

Comment: If i use plain javascript object instead of immutable js i won't face the same problem. I have quickly changed my store to use plain javascript object and useEffect is not getting called when only value is changing.

Comment: Thanks for the info @Amit. The problem is the way Immutable is manipulating the data. I would suggest to switching to [immer](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/docs/introduction) or using Immutable only in the state properties and not in the state itself. Sorry I can not be of more help, lets see if someone can help you better.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Alvaro. It's not easy to replace immutable js now as it's already there in a large codebase.